# Authentication error when creating Azure container application using Terraform and Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker-registry

I am encountering an error while creating a container application in Azure. When I try to create the application using Terraform, I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid value: "testecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/diouxx/glpi:latest": GET https:?scope=repository%3Adiouxx%2Fglpi%3Apull&service=testcontainerregistry.azurecr.io:UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required'.

I have verified that my credentials for the Azure Container Registry (ACR) are correct. I am using Terraform to create the container application and have specified the image 'testecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/diouxx/glpi:latest' in the Terraform configuration file.

Has anyone encountered this issue while creating a container application in Azure using Terraform? Is there something specific I need to configure or check to resolve this authentication error?

Comment: Have you already found a solution? I'm getting the same error with ghcr.io.

Comment: I changed the terraform code
but still the same error but it is not possible to recover the image.

Afterwards I stayed on container apps without using ACR and it works well I gave you the terraform script if you want

Comment: Can you please post the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

It finally works with these parameters using **ghcr.io**:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "YOUR-CONTAINER-NAME" {
  type      = "Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-03-01"
  name      = "YOUR-CONTAINER-NAME"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.aca.id
  location  = azurerm_resource_group.aca.location

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      managedEnvironmentId = azapi_resource.env.id
      configuration = {
        ingress = null
        registries = [{
          server            = "ghcr.io"
          username          = "YOUR-USER-NAME"
          passwordSecretRef = "ghcr-password"
        }]
        secrets = [{
          name  = "ghcr-password"
          value = "YOUR-GITHUB-ACCESS-TOKEN"
        }]
      }

      template = {
        containers = [
          {
            name  = "YOUR-CONTAINER-NAME"
            image = "ghcr.io/YOUR-USER-NAME/YOUR-CONTAINER-NAME:latest"
            resources = {
              cpu    = 0.25
              memory = "0.5Gi"
            }
          }
        ]
        scale = {
          minReplicas = 1
          maxReplicas = 1
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```